# "class ROSBAG_DECL Bag" in bag.h

Tags: ros, syntax

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Will some one please explain me this syntax of defining the class in bag.h

The reason why I have asked this question is - I am facing problem to create a variable/instance/reference to this class.

I don't have much exposure to c++.

Any help would be appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/265459/%22class-rosbag_decl-bag%22-in-bag.h/) by [Hridaynath](https://answers.ros.org/users/30051/hridaynath/) on ROS Answers with karma: 65 on 2017-07-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I don't have much exposure to c++.

This is really a C/C++ question rather than a ROS one. In the future: please try to find a more appropriate forum for these kind of questions.

As to what `ROSBAG_DECL` is: it's a macro that configures visibility of the declaration / definition that follows it. See [ros_comm/tools/rosbag_storage/include/rosbag/macros.h](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/63f8fefadba4d80c38cf544cda4556aa3559cb12/tools/rosbag_storage/include/rosbag/macros.h#L35-L43) for what it does specifically, and see [gcc/wiki/visibility](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility) for general info about symbol visibility.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-07-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0